# Regular Expression to remove Div tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a div tag, nested within many span and div tags.

Now I want a regular expression in JavaScript which will strip the div tags and get the content inside it.

Comment: Do you really need to work on strings or can you work with the DOM? And can you give an example?

Comment: you should probably use an html parser, not regexes.... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  in javascript you should be able to use DOM accessor functions..

Comment: Here is a RegEx that will match your needs: (!?(<.*?>)|[^<]+)\s*
it works for all tags that are encapsulated with < >

Answer (score 6):

You want to remove a `<div>` element from your document?

First things first; learn the DOM!

```
var aReferenceToMyDiv = document.getElementById('foo');
aReferenceToMyDiv.parentNode.removeChild(aReferenceToMyDiv);
```

... will remove the `<div>` element when applied to the following DOM structure:

```
<div id="foo">
    <span>...</span>
    other stuff...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions can't handle nesting, at least JavaScript regexes can't (and those that can, like .NET and PCRE, aren't easy to handle).

This could only work if there is just one outermost `<div>` tag - then the regular expression

```
/<div>.*<\/div>/s`
```

will match everything from the very first `<div>` to the very last `</div>` in your document.